# Litestep disables volume adjustment button

Tags: windows-xp, audio, logitech-headset

[image]

I've been using a Logitech Clearchat Comfort headset for a couple months now, and never had any issues with it until the volume adjustment buttons, that's the thing in the middle of the cord in the stock picture above, decided to quit on me. Sound and other forms of volume control work fine, but I use the headset for everything from gaming to youtube to plain old music playing, so being able to easily change the volume is nice.

The headset uses default windows drivers, so that isn't it, and it hasn't suffered and physical damage that I know of. The only explanation I can easily come up with is that I recently started using Litestep, a windows shell replacement, but I don't see how that would break it. Any ideas?

EDIT: I have confirmed that litestep is causing the problem, but that's all I know.

Answer (score 1):

The WM_APPCOMMAND messages which are used to control volume are not handled directly by LiteStep.  You'll need to install a 3rd party module that will handle those messages, particularly the APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN, APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP and APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE messages.

You'll find more help with LiteStep on irc.freenode.net in #litestep

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried (sorry this is obvious) it on another computer just to see if it works without the Litestep change?

I have had some headsets before where the inline volume adjustment simply was a poorly-constructed potentiometer, and either crackled the audio when adjusted or simply didn't work.

Comment: Hmm, it started working again after switching back to the default shell on the same machine... time for some OP updating.